# Examples of quotients by infinitesimal group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry

I'm looking for examples of *explicit* actions of the infinitesimal group schemes $\alpha_{p^n}$ on schemes (maybe as simple as the affine plane) in characteristic $p$ or mixed characteristic, and their associated quotients.

Tried googling but I couldn't find any explicit examples. Any such or references would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

$\alpha_{p^n}$ is, by definition, the kernel of the $n$-th power of Frobenius on $\mathbb{G}_a$ (which is itself a group scheme) so here is your example. For a different example, take the kernel of the $n$-th power of Frobenius on a supersingular elliptic curve.

Comment: The first of these I kind of figured out myself :) The other one is more interesting (and I knew it, but didn't think about it). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the construction by Moret-Bailly of a nonconstant abelian scheme over $\mathbb{P}^1$. He starts from an abelian surface $A$ containing  $\alpha _p\times \alpha _p$, and takes  the quotient of $A\times \mathbb{P}^1$ by a (nonconstant) subgroupscheme of $(\alpha _p\times \alpha _p)\times \mathbb{P}^1$. Of course such an abelian scheme cannot exist in characteristic 0. This is explained with all details in Exposés 7 and 8 of Astérisque 86.

Comment: The construction itself was known before: for instance it is mentioned in Mumford's *Abelian Varieties*. What I proved in my paper is that the resulting quotient is the Jacobian of a genus 2 fibration over $\mathbb{P}^1$.